# Spark - yarn kills container when exceed memory limit

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

What is the way to reduce the memory usage when writing DF to a file (or files)?

If we increase the number of partitions - will that create a not-necessary shuffle?

What is the best recommendation to improve memory usage without slowing down (too much) execution in PySpark?

Thanks.

Comment: in your final stage lets say you have 200 partitions, it will write 200 files into HDFS. And each partition will open a connection with HDFS to write into the file. I don't believe increase partition while the writing file will increase not-necessary shuffle, it will create more file in the final directory, and speed up write speed, only downside is it might create too much small file if you increase partition too much.

Comment: Ok, do you know how much is too much? What is recommendation or really large dataframes?

Comment: you can estimate the memory by row * column * type of data usage, then times the compression rate of your final storage type like parquet. Or you can go to HDFS, look at your file size, times how many files give you the total output size, then you can divide the size by 128 MB(or your HDFS blocksize). This number is number of partitions.